# Records order after updating mysql table

Tags: mysql

After updating sql table with
`insert into table values (...)` this new record goes as last one in my table. Instead of it I want it to be the first one in my table. So how can I force new record to be first one after updating and records that are already in that table change their position for current position + 1

Comment: That's not how relational databases work. You need to have a column (a simple INT counter would do that AUTO_INCREMENT) that allows you to sort (ORDER BY) - ASC (default) or DESC.

Comment: Another option is a date/time stamp. To clarify: when you do a SELECT.... in MySQL you are not assured of getting the rows returned in the same order (first in, first out) - that's why you need a field to use with ORDER BY. Good luck.